# How to calculate "SLAs" with blackbox-exporter metrics

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I have a blackbox exporter that checks some HTTP endpoints. I've noticed that it doesn't use (rightly) histograms, so I was wondering what's the best way to calculate SLAs for each endpoint?

For instance let's say I check http://google.com, I'd like to calculate:
- the percentage of times I received a valid response (probe_success)
- the percentage of times the response was fetched within X milliseconds

I've tried using avg_over_time:

```
avg_over_time(probe_success{target="https://google.com"}[30d]
```

and dividing by the count of the same metric but I know it's wrong and something's missing

Comment: How do you know it's wrong? Could you elaborate? (I mean apart from the fact that it's missing a closing parenthesis, which I suppose is not what you're getting at.)

Comment: Oh, I can see a possible problem: `avg_over_time()` already produces an average, so you don't need to divide it by anything.

Comment: @AlinSînpălean I don't have histograms (no buckets and no count metric). I'm not sure what's the best way in promql to calculate a percentage (if possible). I know it's wrong because I can't see a way to get a percentage out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`avg_over_time(probe_success[1d])` will give you a ratio between 0 (0%) and 1 (100%). So if you want a percentage out of it, multiply by 100. Or set it up as such in Grafana (I believe it's called "percent (0.0 - 1.0)" or something like that.

If OTOH you want a percentile for some metric, say 90th percentile memory utilization, you'd use something like `quantile_over_time(0.9, memory_utilization[1d])`.

Comment: Thanks! This makes total sense for the success, how would you instead go about doing it for response times?

Comment: Depends on the metrics you have. At the very least you need a request counter and a sum of response times. Then all you need to do is divide the increase in response times by the increase in the number of requests.

Comment: Unfortunately the black box exporter doesn't seem to provide that. It only reports a gauge with the response time of the request.

Comment: Then `avg_over_time(gauge_with_the_response_time[1d])` it is.

Comment: Yes but that would only give me the 50th percentile, any chance I could get another percentile somehow?

Comment: It's not the [50th percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) (or median), it's the [average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) (or mean). If you want a percentile / quantile use `quantile_over_time(0.5, gauge_with_the_response_time[1d])`.

Comment: Awesome! And any chance I could get a percentage out of it? To see if the SLA is breaking or not?

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, why not show the love?